# TypeError: destroy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I keep getting the error above at tkinter.

I kept searching in the __init__.py of *tkinter* and destroy doesn't seem to be getting 2 arguments (so no *event* is needed).

This is invoked when tkinter is trying to destroy a custom class that I have created which is a subclass of Frame.

Before I added this class to the main window, the `root.destroy()`  ,*where root in that case is the main window*, was working fine.
After the addition of the custom class, it destroys only a part of the custom class and then (when probably tries to destroy the other part) it throws that error and does not destroy the root window.

The code for the custom class is:

```
class inputBox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, parentWindow, attrName, label, valueType, query=None ):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.attrName = attrName
        self.label = tk.Label(self,text=label)
        self.valueType = valueType

        if 'enum' in valueType:
            values = valueType.replace("enum(","").replace(")","").split(",")

        elif 'varchar' in valueType:
            maxChars = int(valueType.replace("varchar(","").replace(")",""))
            if query:
                self.query=query
                success,result = DAO().executeQuery(query,'select')
                self.autoCompletedEntry = AutocompletedEntry(self, result, parentWindow, listboxLength=6, width = maxChars)
                self.label.pack()
                self.autoCompletedEntry.pack()
```

The code for the AutocompletedEntry (**which is the class that probably creates the error**) is:

```
class AutocompletedEntry(tk.Frame):
    #rootsParent is needed only for the popup autocompletion list
    def __init__(self, root, autocompleteList, rootsParent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root)

        self.rootsParent = rootsParent
        self.var = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.var.trace("w", self.changed)#lambda name, index, mode, self.var=self.var: callback(self.var))


        if 'width' in kwargs:
            self.width = int(int(kwargs['width'])//3)
            del kwargs['width']
            if self.width >40:
                self.width = 40
        else:
            self.width = 25

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=self.width, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.pack(side='left',fill='both')

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='▼',command=lambda: self.changed('','','arrow'))

        self.button.pack(side='right')

        # Listbox length
        if 'listboxLength' in kwargs:
            self.listboxLength = kwargs['listboxLength']
            del kwargs['listboxLength']
        else:
            self.listboxLength = 8

        # Custom matches function
        if 'matchesFunction' in kwargs:
            self.matchesFunction = kwargs['matchesFunction']
            del kwargs['matchesFunction']
        else:
            def matches(fieldValue, acListEntry):
                pattern = re.compile(re.escape(fieldValue) + '.*', re.IGNORECASE)
                return re.match(pattern, acListEntry)

            self.matchesFunction = matches

        self.focus()

        self.autocompleteList = sorted(autocompleteList)

        self.listboxUp = False        

        self.entry.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.selection)
        self.entry.bind("<Up>", self.moveUp)
        self.entry.bind("<Down>", lambda e: self.moveDown(e))
        self.entry.bind("<Escape>", self.destroy)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We can't debug your code without seeing it. Please read [mcve].

Comment: You were right, sorry. Now I think it is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you using `event` to `destroy` you need parse `event` as parameter to the function.So i will suggest you create `function` and parse `event` as parameter for the window to be destroy

Example:

```
def destroy_root(self, event):
    self.root.destroy
```

then you use it for your event `"<Escape>"` to able to destroy your `window`.

Comment: the code you posted doesn't output the error so this suggestion to achieve the result.

Comment: That was it dude! Basically, it was local method which by coincidence it was called destroy, it wasn't intended to destroy the root window, but rather a popup window. Nonetheless, tkinter seemed to be confusing that with the tk.destroy method. Thank you so much!
I just had to rename the local method to destroyPopUp and it was done!

Comment: @Pontios: tkinter wasn't _confusing_ it -- you were explicitly telling it to call your local method named `destroy`.

Comment: I agree, I was basically overriding the method.